# Show that 1/((z-1)*(z-i) is the limit of a geometric sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

given is a function g, which assigns to every z of complex numbers the value 1/((z-1)*(z-i)) 
I have to show that it is possible to denote the value above as a limit of a geometric sequence $\sum_{k=0}^\infty = \frac{1}{(z-i)*(z-1)}$. For example, the previous question was z to 1/(1-z), which could be described as the usual limit of an ordinary geometric sequence. What strucks me here is the imaginary unit, as I do not know how to eliminate it from the sequence. Do you have any tips? I tried to do partial fractions but did not manage to continue from there.

I will put my solution on here and hope someone can correct any mistakes:

Starting with  $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-i)}$ I use partial fractions and get $\frac{1}{(1-i)}\left(\frac{1}{(z-1)}-\frac{1}{(z-i)}\right)$
I rewrite that as $\frac{i}{(1-i)}\left(\frac{-1}{(1-z)}(\frac{1}{i})-\frac{1}{1+iz})\right)$
I then write the first expression as $\left(\frac{-1}{1-i}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{1-i}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ minus the second, which is term $\left(\frac{i}{1-i}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-iz)^n$. So combined it would be $$\left(\frac{-1}{1-i}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n - \left(\frac{i}{1-i}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-iz)^n$$
Am I right?

Kind Regards

Comment: Use Mathjax please

Comment: Are you after $$\frac1{(z-1)(z-i)}=-\frac{1+i}2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-(-i)^{n+1})z^n\ ?$$

Comment: Exactly. But how do I get there? I started with partial fractions but was not able to continue.

Comment: Maybe someone else? I appreciate your time:)

Comment: Using @ would be an option. Starting to add something personal would be another. Both could be used simultaneously.

Comment: @Did Well what I personally started with, was, as I said, to use partial fractions. What i get as an output there is:$$\frac{-i}{i+1}*(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z-i})$$ I do not know if that is right. If it is, I could write $$\frac{1}{z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^k$$ and $$\frac{1}{z-i}=\frac{i}{1+iz}$$ and then write that as $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-iz)^k$$

Comment: So you WERE actually "able to continue", right? As I said, the details of the computations you tried should be in your question, not in comments. And sorry but at present, I fail to see what prevents you to conclude...

Comment: @Did What prevents me to conclude is that I do not know if the calculations above are right. It would be kind to tell me if I made mistake or not, if not, all my questions are answered. And I still wonder how to get to the point you pointed out earlier. Kind Regards

Comment: Suggestion: write completely the solution you have, post it as an answer, then everybody will be able to check it.

Comment: @Did I put my solution underneath the quesiton so everyone cn check it. Kind Regards

Comment: Excellent. Now you might complete your computations by writing the result as a single power series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$ Also, using $$\frac1{1-i}=\frac{1+i}2$$ might be seen as a simplification in your final formula.

Comment: thank you very much, got it now:)